# Concatenating a variable in Jinja with a single quote

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I'm having trouble trying to concatenate variables (one with a single quote) in Jinja. My code looks like this:

```
{%- set my_quote = "'" -%}
{%- set invocation =  invocation_id -%}
```

And the output I'm attempting is this:

```
{{ invocation ~ my_quote }}
```

The output from this is:

```
f21f9039-44e5-452f-8d7a-ee64245ada23'
```

Ok great! Now when I attempt to add the single quote to the beginning as well:

```
{{ my_quote ~ invocation ~ my_quote }}
```

The output is the invocation variable value without any single quotes:

```
f21f9039-44e5-452f-8d7a-ee64245ada23
```

How can I get this to output both single quotes properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

`"'{{ invocation_id }}'"`

Comment: That did it. TYVM!

Answer (score 0):

oh I love this question and the great reproducible example you provided. First thought, what happens if you escape the `'` like this?

```sql
{%- set my_quote = "\'" -%}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it has the same result, no single quotes.

Comment: bummer! i just made a [dbt Slack thread](https://getdbt.slack.com/archives/C2JRRQDTL/p1631827259363000) to see if anyone else can help.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason it has to be part of the variable?

Could you do:

```
'{{ invocation }}'
```

Comment: There is no reason, and unfortunately that returns the invocation value without single quotes as well